# Image slide show animation doesn't animate

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an animated slide show. This code works but without animation so I see the change of position when the function ends, and it's take the time suppose to animate

```
function slide()
{
for (var i=0;i<100;i++)
{
setTimeout("realslide(i);",100);
}

};

function realslide(ii){
var I=ii;
var s_e=document.getElementById("slide_element");
var po="-"+i+"px";
se.style.left=po;
};
```

Comment: why you need to reinvent the wheels since many available slideshow plugins out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given too less time for observing the animation behavior. Change the time stamp to say 3 seconds, 3000 instead of 1 millisecond 100

See my Comment

Comment: but it have 10 steps so 100*100=100000 MS or 10 second

Comment: @Karim: It doesn't work that way. 3 secs will go for one animation. Actually you should move your setTimeout outside the for loop